# OpenStack using one public IP address from multiple servers

Tags: routing, openstack

I am testing out openstack and have it all configured but with my current setup I have only one public IP address which is assigned to the servers public interface.

Is it possible to assign multiple dns records for different domains to the public ip address and then route the packets to the individual virtual server using some sort of routing table in openstack?

This probably isnt possible but I was interested to see if it had been done.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Remember to get IPv6 so you don't have to worry so much about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually do this by assigning the public IP address to one server and running a reverse proxy on it. One popular choice for this is nginx. You can find a configuration example [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can not resolve this issue with routing. I recommand that you set up a reverse proxy and assign your public IP to it. then you set up your reverse proxy to redirect requests for a particular domain to the virtual server of your choice.